# Confusion regarding minimal degree.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm reading up the proof to Hilbert's Basis Theorem from [here](http://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Hilbert_s_basis_theorem.html). I'm quoting the lines that are confusing me.

*Let $I$ be an ideal in $R[X]$ and assume for a contradiction that $I$ is not finitely generated. Inductively construct a sequence $f_{1}, f_{2},\dots$ of elements of $I$ such that **$f_{i+1}$ has minimal degree in $I \setminus J_{i}$**, where $J_{i}$ is the ideal generated by $f_{1}, ..., f_{i}$.*

I don't understand the phrase "$f_{i+1}$ has minimal degree in $I \setminus J_{i}$". Does this mean that $f_{i+1}$ can't be a polynomial of a lower degree in any other ideal/subring of $R[X]$?

Comment: Consider the set $I\setminus J_i$. From that set, choose an element $g$ such that $\deg(g) = \min \{\deg f \colon f \in I\setminus J_i\}$. Also: rewrite the sentence "such that $\deg f_{i+1} = \min \{\deg f \colon f \in I\setminus J_i\}$, where ..."

Comment: Won't $f_{i}$ always be a polynomial of degree $1$ then? I suppose the minimum degree in the ideal has to be $1$; $(x-a)$, where $a\in I\setminus J_{i}$

Comment: No, $f_i$ is always an element of $I$. If $I \subset (X^2)$, for example, $\deg f_i \geqslant 2$ for all $i$.

Comment: True. But here we're concerned with ideals $I\subset R[X]$, and not $R[X^2]$. Won't the minimum degree be $1$? Terribly sorry if this is sounding repetitive. Thanks.

Comment: $(X^2)$ is an ideal in $R[X]$, it contains for example $X^2 + X^3 = (X+1)\cdot X^2$, so it's not contained in $R[X^2]$.

Comment: oh ok. Sorry. I thought $(X^2)$ must have been a typo for $R[X^2]$